# Webbrowser doesn't open pdf file with python

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I was trying to open the same pdf file twice with a python script. Once in Adobe Acrobat and once in chrome.

The part with opening the file in Acrobat wasn't a problem, but i can't open it in chrome. If i run the script nothing happend with chrome and i couldn't find the problem. Here you can see the code.
I also tried to do just webbrowser.open (without define chrome before) but then the file will be opened in Adobe Acrobat too.

```
chrome = webbrowser.get('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s')
chrome.open_new(r'file:///C:/Users/#PATH#.PDF')
```

Comment: Don't you need to either make that first path an `r` string, or double up your backslashes? - could the problem be that simple?

Answer (score 0):

i tested the given answers but this doesn't work.
But i had the idea to use the relative Path from the python script to chrome and this worked.
It looks like this now:

```
webbrowser.get(r'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s').open(openingPath)
```

Now the given file will be opened in Chrome